# Display Multiple posts on Github pages using poole

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-bootstrap

I am trying to set up my blog on Github pages using Jekyll, as per the following template. https://github.com/poole/poole

The problem is, it displays only one post on the page, whereas I want it to display multiple posts on a single page, with the title and some part of the content. Has anyone dealt with this issue before? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You just need to learn how jekyll works with liquid to do whatever you want. I would suggest you watch some videos on youtube and check out the docs on jekyllrb.com. This may help too: https://github.com/mdo/jekyll-snippets

Comment: Thank you for the link. I did figure it out eventually by reading through Jekyll documentation.

Answer (score 1):

After going through the Jekyll documentation, I did figure it out. I will post what I did so that it helps anyone trying to do the same.

1. In `config.yml`, change the value of paginate from 1 to 5(or whatever number of posts you want to display)
2. In index.html, change `{{ post.content }}` to `{{ post.excerpt }}`. By default it displays the first paragraph. You can learn about excerpts and how to set a different separator here. http://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/